# Redirect to a page after a few seconds

Tags: redirect

I have homepage which needs to redirect to another page. For this to accomplish, I used the `meta fresh` tag

```
<meta http-equiiv=refresh content="6; url=/home/">
```

And, it works perfectly. Later I found on Internet that this `meta fresh` code tag has been deprecated and is not at all SEO friendly.

Then I used one js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location='url'",5000);
</script>
```

and it's also working.. now, my concern is - which one still better (most SEO friendly or is there any other hack in redirecting a simple page to another WP normal page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your goal is to misdirect a search engine into believing the content is there then JavaScript won't help.  Google's engine is sophisticated enough to realize you're changing the URL.  If your intention is to have a URL actually redirect to _correct_ content then you'll want to use wp_redirect() as below.  There isn't really a great reason to show a page for 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. honestly speaking, the front page is kind of a landing page with just a welcome message and with a link to the actual homepage. However, I wish the page automatically goes to the homepage (the actual homepage I mean). There is virtually no substance in the front page. However, I have also thought of noindexing the frontpage www.example.com and making the homepage www.exampple.com/home/ the actual homepage. makes sense?

Comment: Then remove that "landing" page. Those things are just annoying. You are competing enough online without irritating your users with pointless "features"

Comment: If your concern is SEO you should do 301 redirect.

Answer (score 5):

Though `wp_redirect()` doesn't allow a delay, PHP's `header()` ( which is what wp_redirect [uses](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1168) ) does via [refresh](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114).

This may work for you.

```
<?php 
  header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" ); 
  echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="wherever.php">here</a>.';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this:

1 Using [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Add following code to top of index.php

```
<?php if (is_home() || is_front_page())  wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; ?>
```

Or create new page template if you are using page as front page

```
<?php /*  
Template Name: Page Redirect
*/ 

 wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; 

?>
```

2 Using a plugin, [Quick Page/Post Redirect](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/)

Comment: Kate, don't rollback my formatting. Please, when you add code to your posts, highlight the code, and check just above the editor, there are a `{}` sign. Click on that, your code will be automatically be added to a code block, this will display your code as in my edit

Comment: Thanks but how to use this with a timeout (redirect after a few seconds)

Comment: You cannot. The only way to have a delayed redirection is using JS.

Comment: Yup, I hove also figured this out. So, this js code is okay?    `<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location='url'",5000);
</script>`

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirection-after-time/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not the coding type, but you want an amazingly versatile free tool, I endorse Quick Pagepost Redirect Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

It can handle Wordpress redirects and meta redirects (in case you need a delay)

It supports 301, 302, 307, and meta redirects.
You can add URL's to avoid 404's also.

If you are upgrading a site and changing page urls and wish to preserve seo ranking, this is the tool my friend uses (he's a pro)

This will do it all - no coding.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with these guys in any way.

Answer (score -1):

How about just using php sleep to delay the wp_redirect for a few seconds?

```
<?php
sleep(3);
wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
?>
```

Comment: i think this would not work, because you can't see the page while is "sleeping"